# Obtener número de teléfono android sin permisos en Android

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola, me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de obtener el número de teléfono sin permisos. Instagram lo hace, no se como.

Los permisos esta desactivados y aún así logra printar mi número de teléfono.

De la forma:

```
 TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mPhoneNumber = mngr.getLine1Number();
```

No me sirve ya que me pide permisos.

Si alguno sabe una forma, gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido Eduardo, para que la pregunta sea mejor recibida revisa [ask]

Answer (score 4):

**No existe una forma para poder obtener el id del dispositivo mediante el método [getDeviceId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId()) sin declarar [READ_PHONE_STATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_PHONE_STATE), es requisito indispensable declarar este permiso**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Los permisos son para que visualmente el usuario acepte o no la instalación de la aplicación, en el caso de la aplicación que mencionas muestra el teléfono, pero lo obtiene ya que requiere el permiso [READ_PHONE_STATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_PHONE_STATE) :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Te sugiero ahora usar el método [getMeid()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getMeid()) ya que [getDeviceId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId()) esta marcado como obsoleto desde API la 26.

Comment: Hola Jorgesys, sí. Pero lo que yo quiero es el número de teléfono. He visto que instagram lo muestra sin ningún permiso. No se de que forma lo hace

Comment: Lo muestra cuando abres la aplicación, después de instalarla, si la instalas aceptaste el permiso.